# Как автоматизировать подстановку чисел в формулы Microsoft Office Word из Microsoft Office Excel

Tags: excel, ms-word, excel-формулы

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, необходимо автоматизировать подстановку значений из ячеек Microsoft Office Excel в формулы Microsoft Office Word. Как сделать подстановку через специальную вставку разобрался, но возникла вторая проблема, при закрытии документа все связи либо пропадают, либо не работают. Перепробовал разные методы, и ничего не вышло. Все работает пока не закроешь один из документов.